# Curved Path Constant Speed and End Points

Tags: java, libgdx, spline, derivative

I’m trying to move at a constant speed over a curved path in a given amount of time. I calculated the average speed needed to travel the curve by taking the derivative at various points along the curve and averaging them. Then I multiply the path’s position (t) by a ratio of the average derivative and the derivative at the current location of the curve. This method for setting constant speed works great.

The problem I’m having occurs when multiple control points (3 or more) are put in the same location. Then the speed (or derivative) at this point is 0 and dividing the average speed by a speed of 0 obviously causes problems in the calculations.

BSpline requires three control points to be placed at the ends in order to have the curve actually reach the start and end at the end points. If I only put 1 or 2 control points at the ends the path starts after the first control point and ends before the last control point. For my application it is important that the motion reaches the end points because I will be linking together multiple BSplines and it’s important for them to line up correctly and to not have any time gaps between them either.

I’ve tried a few different attempts at fixing it, but none of them were successful.

Here is my sample code and I've included comments to indicate where the problem is.

***NOTE:*** I used CatmullRomSpline in my example instead of BSpline only because I found a bug in the BSpline’s derivative method, which has been fixed but is not yet in the stable version of LibGDX.

**Test.java**

```
public class Test extends Game {
    private Stage stage;
    private MyPath path;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(1000, 1000, false);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setViewport(new ScreenViewport(stage.getViewport().getCamera()));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        path = new MyPath(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        stage.addActor(path);
    }
    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        path.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

**MyPath.java**

```
public class MyPath extends WidgetGroup implements Disposable {
    private Path<Vector2> path;
    private Vector2 result=new Vector2(), derivative=new Vector2();
    private float time, t, tPrev, dt, tConst, tConstPrev, derivativeAverage;
    private Array<Texture> textures = new Array<Texture>(Texture.class);
    private Array<Image> points = new Array<Image>(Image.class);
    private Image dot;

    private final float CYCLE = 4;  // path cycle time (in seconds)

    private Vector2[] pointsData = {
            new Vector2(100, 100),
            new Vector2(100, 100),
//          new Vector2(100, 100),  // << UN-COMMENT TO PRODUCE BUG

            new Vector2(350, 800),
            new Vector2(550, 200),
            new Vector2(650, 400),
            new Vector2(900, 100),
            new Vector2(900, 100)
    };

    public MyPath(int width, int height){
        this.setSize(width, height);        
        path = new CatmullRomSpline<Vector2>(pointsData, false);
        // create and add images
        createImages();
        for (int i=0; i<points.size; i++){
            points.items[i].setPosition(pointsData[i].x - points.items[i].getWidth()/2, pointsData[i].y - points.items[i].getHeight()/2);
            addActor(points.items[i]);
        }
        addActor(dot);

        // calculate derivative average
        derivativeAverage();
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        result = getValue(delta);
        dot.setPosition(result.x - dot.getWidth()/2, result.y - dot.getHeight()/2);     
    }
    private Vector2 getValue(float delta){
        // set t in the range [0,1] for path
        time += delta;
        if (time > CYCLE){
            time = tPrev = dt = tConst = tConstPrev = 0;
        }
        t = time / CYCLE;
        dt = t - tPrev;
        tPrev = t;

        // constant speed (tConst)
        path.derivativeAt(derivative, tConstPrev);
        tConst += dt * (derivativeAverage / derivative.len());  // << ERROR when derivative.len() is 0
        tConstPrev = tConst;

        path.valueAt(result, tConst);

        return result;
    }

    private void derivativeAverage(){
        float segmentCount = 20000;
        derivativeAverage = 0;      
        for (float i=0; i<=1; i+=1.0/segmentCount) {    
            path.derivativeAt(result, i);
            derivativeAverage += result.len();          
        }
        derivativeAverage /= segmentCount;
        if (derivativeAverage==0){ throw new GdxRuntimeException("ERROR: derivative average is zero"); }
    }

    private void createImages(){
        dot = getImage(Color.GREEN, true);
        for (int i=0; i<pointsData.length; i++){
            points.add(getImage(Color.WHITE, false));
        }
    }
    private Image getImage(Color color, boolean fillCircle){
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(50, 50, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(color);
        if (fillCircle){
            pixmap.fillCircle(pixmap.getWidth()/2, pixmap.getHeight()/2, pixmap.getWidth()/2-1);
        } else {
            pixmap.drawCircle(pixmap.getWidth()/2, pixmap.getHeight()/2, pixmap.getWidth()/2-1);
        }
        textures.add(new Texture(pixmap));
        pixmap.dispose();
        return new Image(textures.peek());
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        while (textures.size > 0){
            textures.pop().dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

===================================================================

***EDIT***

===================================================================

Here is my latest attempt at increasing t until the dot is moving.

This method does occasionally work on some frames (moving smoothly past the zero derivative). But other times the dot does weird things lie starting over at the beginning of the curve when it hits the zero derivative or extending beyond the end of the curve moving a different direction or disappearing completely (because the position gets set to negative values).

So it seems like this method is really close as it does occasionally work on some frames, but it glitches and does weird things on other frames.

```
Vector2 lastPoint = new Vector2();
float minSpeed = 1;
float minDerivative = 1;
float temp;

...

private Vector2 getValue(float delta){      
    // set t in the range [0,1] for path
    time += delta;
    if (time > CYCLE){
        time = tPrev = dt = tConst = tConstPrev = 0;
    }
    t = time / CYCLE;

    // CONSTANT SPEED
    dt = t - tPrev;
    path.derivativeAt(derivative, tConstPrev);
    temp = dt * (derivativeAverage / derivative.len());
    path.valueAt(result, tConst + temp);

    //**************************************
    //  FIX FOR ZERO SPEED
    //  increase t in loop until speed > 0
    //**************************************
    while (result.dst(lastPoint)<minSpeed || derivative.len()<minDerivative){
        // set t in the range [0,1] for path
        time += delta;
        if (time > CYCLE){
            time = tPrev = dt = tConst = tConstPrev = 0;
            lastPoint.set(0,0);         
        }
        t = time / CYCLE;

        // CONSTANT SPEED
        dt = t - tPrev;
        // new derivative
        path.valueAt(derivative, t);
        derivative.sub(lastPoint);

        temp = dt * (speedAverage / derivative.len());
        path.valueAt(result, tConst + temp);
    }

    tConst += temp;

    lastPoint.set(result);
    tPrev = t;
    tConstPrev = tConst;

    return result;
}
```

I also do a similar thing when calculating the average speed to keep the zero derivatives from affecting it. I also tried using the commented out sections with the "addedSegmentCount" variable when calculating the average, but that actually caused more glitches for some reason...even though theoretically this seems like the "correct" way to calculate the average since some segments don't get added if the distance is too small.

```
private void pathLength_SpeedAverage(){
    float segmentCount = 20000;
//  float addedSegmentCount = 0;
    pathLength = 0;

    path.valueAt(lastPoint, 0);
    for (float i=0; i<=1; i+=1.0/segmentCount){
        path.valueAt(result, i);
        if (result.dst(lastPoint) >= minSpeed){
            path.derivativeAt(result, i);
            if (result.len() >= minDerivative){
                pathLength += result.len();

                lastPoint.set(result);
//              ++addedSegmentCount;
            }
        }
    }
    speedAverage = pathLength / segmentCount;
//  speedAverage = pathLength / addedSegmentCount;
    lastPoint.set(0,0);
}
```

Comment: B-spline does not require you to add multiple control points at the ends so as for the curve to reach the start and end points unless you are using non-clamped knot sequence such as [0, 0.1, 0.2, ...., 0.9, 1.0]. If you uses clamped knot sequence such as [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2,...., 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1], then the curve will start and ends at the first and last control points. Having said this, if you had switched to Catmull-Rom spline, do you still have the same problem (encountering zero derivative)?

Comment: Yes, I do have the same zero (or near zero) derivative problem with CatmullRom if I set 3 (or more) control points in the same location. Regarding BSpline, I looked at the LibGDX source code and it doesn’t appear that the knots are used in the valueAt() or derivativeAt() methods. I tested it by clearing the knot array and assigning my own values to it and the path remained the same. So how would I go about setting different knot sequences? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you duplicated consecutive points, you will get zero derivatives. But this happens regardless which kind of interpolation you used. I am not familiar with LibGDX. I was just commenting from the perspective of B-spline theory. Sorry.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to smoothly step over these areas with multiple control points and get back into the path where the derivatives are no longer zero (or close to zero)? I've tried a few different methods like increasing the time interval by the normal amount (instead of the derivative ratio) until the derivative is greater than 1. But I always end up causing glitches and it doesn't smoothly move past the multiple control points. Also, LibGDX is open source and here is the source for BSpline: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/BSpline.java

Comment: For cubic B-spline, you need to have 4 consecutive control points for the corresponding Bezier segment to become a point. Let's say you have 6 control points P0,P1,P2,...P5 with P1,P2,P3 and P4 being at the same location and a knot sequence [0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0], then the derivative evaluation within (0.3,0.7) will be zero and you just need to skip this range for derivative evaluation.

Comment: I made a copy of the BSpline class so I could put some print statements in to see what it was doing at each frame. I also removed the constant speed derivative ratio code for these tests and used 7 control points where the first 3 are the same. During knot span 1 the derivative ranges from 0 to 346.3167 and the position on the curve changes from the starting control point (100, 100) to (137.47958, 204.94284). I posted my print statements to textuploader. http://textuploader.com/5wg7h So it doesn’t appear I can skip the first curve entirely as there is quite a bit of movement during it. Thanks.

Comment: Having 4 consecutive identical control points will certainly make a cubic Bezier segment become a point, which leads to zero first derivative. But this is not the "only" way that will lead to zero first derivative. For example, if you have the first two control points the same, you will have zero first derivative at t=0.0. Even for a single cubic Bezier curve with all 4 distinct control points, you still could encounter zero first derivative at certain parameter value. So, if you really want to skip zero first derivatives, the best way is simply not to include them when computing the average.

Comment: I think you can also get the average speed by dividing the overall length of the path by the parameter range.  To compute the overall length of the path, you can sample sufficient points along the path and compute the cumulative chord length as accuracy is not really important here. This way, you don't really care about zero first derivatives at all.

Comment: The BSpline class has an approxLength method that I can use to get the length of the curve. But what can I do about having to get current speed? At each frame I'm evening out the speed by multiplying t by (averageSpeed / currentSpeed) and the currentSpeed is what is causing the problems. In order to get the current speed at a particular point in the curve I have to get the derivative at that point. Is there another way to offset "t" at a particular point to keep constant speed without dealing with the derivative at that point? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot completely avoid zero first derivatives if control points could be coincident. So, what I suggest is to not use the zero first derivatives at all. Your purpose is to traverse the path at a constant speed, which is equivalent to sample points along the path with equal arc length, You should be able to find many examples in SO on this topic.

Comment: I have looked into arc length parameterization and it seems to be very, very complicated. For example, this pdf pops up in most threads on this topic. https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MovingAlongCurveSpecifiedSpeed.pdf And I've read some other stuff on arc lengths but I still do not understand how to calculate the curve parameter t that corresponds to a specific arc length. If I could get that part, then I could definitely go the arc length route instead. But it's been a while since I've had to do calculus in college and actually grasping this stuff so I can code it is difficult.

Comment: The theoretical approach involves calculus indeed, but you can go with the approximation approach, which I will post as an answer (as it takes a couple steps).

Comment: Great thanks! And since you clearly understand this stuff really well, would it be possible to also explain the calculus version of calculating t in plain english? It seems like some of the documents trying to explain it way over-complicate things. lol But to see it presented in the step-by-step approach like you did would probably make it much clearer. Thanks again for all your help! :)

Comment: It is not easy to explain math and complex numeric methods in plain English and within limited character counts. All I can tell you is that the  equation(5) and (6) in the pdf file you reference above actually correspond to the lookup table (step 3) and linear interpolation (step 4) in my answer. It is just that the approach in my answer is an approximation to the real solution but is much easier to understand implement.

Comment: If you wanted to post another answer (or edit your answer to include the advanced calculus method) then you wouldn't be constrained to the character limit. But I'll take a look at the document again and compare to your approximation example. Your example was easy to intuitively understand so maybe that will help make the long mathematical document more digestible. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Also, I've still been working on a less math intensive solution, because everything works except for the one special case where the dot is not moving (derivative=0 or small enough that the dot's position doesn't change by even 1 pixel). So my idea is: IF dot is moving THEN make speed constant. IF dot is not moving THEN move to a frame where the dot is moving THEN make that speed constant. Basically just increasing the curve parameter in a loop until the dot moves and then use my constant speed derivative ratio on it. Does this seem plausible? I can edit my post to show what I have so far.

Comment: I just edited my original post to include my latest method to transition over the zero speed/derivative. Do you think something like that would be a viable solution or am I wasting my efforts trying to fix the problem like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot completely avoid zero first derivatives if control points could be coincident. So, what I suggest is to not use the first derivatives at all. Your purpose is to traverse the path at a constant speed, which is equivalent to sample points along the path with equal arc length. The theoretical approach to solve this involves calculus to compute arc length numerically, but we can go with an approximation approach as in the following:

Suppose you would like to traverse the path in N steps,
1) Sample M points along the path uniformly in parameter domain (i.e., t=0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ....) where M is preferred to be greater than N. Denoting these points as P0, P1, P2,....
2) Compute the distance between P0P1, P1P2, P2P3,....
3) Compile a look-up table that maps from parameter t(i) to the cumulative chord length |P0P1|+|P1P2|+.....+|P(i-1)P(i)|. At the end, you will also obtain the overall length of the path, denoted as L. 
4) Now, for each value of k*L/N (where k=0 to N), you can compute the corresponding t value from the look-up table by linear interpolating the two parameter values in which the k*L/N falls on.

Comment: Woohoo! I got this method working. :) I was worried initially that I was going to need to store thousands and thousands of values in the lookup table in order for it to be precise and I only need about 100 and it looks to be about perfect. Wow, this really is a great method. It currently freezes for a split second right at the very beginning, but I hopefully I'll be able to figure that out. Thanks again for all you're help. :)

Comment: Hello @fang, I know this is old, but is it possible to add some more details to this answer, mainly on point 4 which is too difficult to understand for me?

Comment: Suppose you have a lookup table that maps parameters [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,0.4,....1.0] to arc length [0, 8, 15, 23, 32, .....100] and you want to find the parameter at which the arc length is 28, you will loop thru the arc length array to find out the two bounding values 23 and 32, then linear interpolate the corresponding parameters 0.3 and 0.4 to find the parameter.  Hope this clearly enough.

Comment: @fangThank you! I used an array of lengths instead of a lookup table; then used an invLerp to find "t" for "28" between "23" and "32" and then I used a lerp between samples[0.3] and samples[0.4] with the "t" param... is it correct?

Comment: @camillo: if invLerp gives you a value = 5/9 and lerp gives you a value = 0.3555555, then it is correct.